# Let G be a graph such that $\delta (G) = n(G) − 2$. Prove that $\kappa (G) = \delta (G)$.

Tags: graph-theory

I know if $\delta (G) = n(G) − 1$, $\kappa(G) = \delta(G)$ as $G$ is just a complete graph. But, how do I prove it for $\delta(G) = n(G) − 2$?

Comment: What are $\delta(G), n(G)$ and $\kappa(G)$?

Comment: It works for any n(G) greater than 2

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=n(G)$ and suppose $\kappa(G)<n-2$.
Then there is a separating set (vertex cut) $S$ of size exactly $n-3$ (verify!).

$G-S$ is disconnected and has exactly 3 elements, so it has an isolated vertex $v$.

But $v$ has degree at least $n-2$ and it has at most $n-3$ edges to $S$, so it cannot be isolated. Contradiction.